# Prevent automatic close of the Facebook share popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I am using below mentioned code to share my page into Facebook.

My problem is when i click the share button it shares my page correctly but it closes the popup window but i don't want to close the popup.Please advice me.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>fb</title>

</head>
<body>

<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://google.com', 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>

</body>
</html>
```